# Como remover barra de ferramentas do tinymce?

Tags: tinymce-4

Bom dia pessoal, eu consegui limitar os botões do tinymce da seguinte forma:

```
editor_config.toolbar1 = "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | emoticons";
editor_config.toolbar2 = "";
```

Porem, eu não consegui descobrir como remover a barra de ferramentas que está na imagem abaixo, alguém sabe me dizer como faço para remover?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo que configura/customiza o Menu e seus respectivos botões é o `menu`.

Da forma que você está utilizando, creio que irá conseguir retirar os botões desta forma:

```
editor_config.menu = {}
```

Existe uma outra forma de implementar a chamada do Tinymce em forma de Json.

Por exemplo:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#textarea",
  toolbar: "bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
  menu : {},
  plugins: "link",
  link_list: [{title: 'Custumer', value: 'http://www.mywebsite.com.br'}],
  target_list: [{title: 'Mesma Página', value: '_self'},{title: 'Nova Aba', value: '_blank'}]
});
```

Logicamente, o jeito que você pretende implementar vai da sua escolha, de como você acha mais fácil e melhor para possíveis manutenções.